# ¿Por qué no me une los puntos en mi gráfica?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo que representar una gráfica y con puntos y lineas que unan esos simulando una curva pero solo me representa los puntos:

```
porcentaje=('25%','50%','75%','100%','125%','150%','175%','200%')
pa_eq_test=(72.909,75.645,78.728,82.509,81.463,84.721,82.979,81.063)

for k in range(len(pa_eq_test)):  

    plt.plot(porcentaje[k],pa_eq_test[k],'go')
    plt.xlabel("Porcentajes ")
    plt.ylabel("Prob. acierto equilibrada test")
```

He probado con `'go--'` dentro del `plot` pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Dos cosas:

- **Estás realizando 8 gráficos en el mismo eje**, no uno, cada llamada a `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` genera una nueva línea, no un punto. No necesitas iterar.
- El formato que indicas ("go") especifica que no se unan los puntos:

  - **`g`** -> color verde, "**g**reen".
  - **`o`** -> [formato para el marcador](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/markers_api.html), círculo.

  Falta:

  - **`-`** -> Unir los marcadores con una línea sólida continua

El resto de opciones para la línea (de la [documentación oficial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html)):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

porcentaje=('25%','50%','75%','100%','125%','150%','175%','200%')
pa_eq_test=(72.909,75.645,78.728,82.509,81.463,84.721,82.979,81.063)

plt.plot(porcentaje, pa_eq_test, 'go-')
plt.xlabel("Porcentajes ")
plt.ylabel("Prob. acierto equilibrada test")

plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]